# Classic ASP - Session ID Length

Tags: asp-classic, sessionid

Is it possible to change the Session.SessionID length in Classic ASP running on IIS6?

ALSO

SessionID's seem to be quite predictable as they are following a pattern. Is there a way to make it more random? (i.e. increase the entropy level.)

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Pattern? Really? See "Hard-to-Guess Cookie Values" section in the link provided by @Gerrat.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simple answer is no, but more details about your options can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972338.aspx)